# Power BI refresh multiply currencies

Tags: powerbi, azure-blob-storage, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI dashboard that is reading .CSV files form an Azure Storage Account.

I'm using it to compare our Azure costs and on the Power BI Desktop everything is fine. The columns are created from the `costInBillingCurrency` to which I gave:

- Data type: Decimal number
- Format: Currency

[image]

So I publish it online and I see the same result. Beautiful.

Then I wait 24h, the data refresh pulling the data from the Azure Storage Account, all broken:

[image]

It seems like that the currency is multiplied multiple times.

What it is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Data type form `Decimal number` to `Fixed decimal number`.

And this is actually how money should be treated, as per the icon next to it:

[image]